# How does PFUser currentUser work on WatchOS 2?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, watchos-2

I'm migrating from a WatchOS 1 app to a WatchOS 2 app, which uses the Parse SDK. Before my iOS parent app did all of the Parse heavy lifting, and now that the Parse SDK natively supports WatchOS 2 I'd like to move that to the watch instead so the app can run without the phone app running.

How do we handle authenticating the user? As they're totally separate now, I don't think I can just use the `PFUser` `currentUser` method to get the current user. I could try to get an authentication token from the iOS app and then perform another login on the watch to store its own `currentUser`, but then I would be relying on the iOS app again, and if the user logged out on the iOS app the watch app may still be logged in to the wrong account.

How are people handling this?